# Solving a non-linear congruence for $f\in \mathbb{F}_5[x]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

How can we find a solution $f\in \mathbb{F}_5[x]$ for the following non-linear congruence?

$ f\equiv 1\mod{x}+1,\ x\cdot f\equiv x+1\mod{x^2}+1,\ (x+1)\cdot f\equiv x+ 1\mod{x^3}+1  $

Comment: Here $(x^3+1)=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, so the last congruence is equivalent to $f\equiv1\pmod{x^2-x+1}$. Therefore, by the Chinese remainder theorem, the first and the last combine to read $f\equiv1\pmod{x^3+1}$. In $\Bbb{F}_5[x]$ we have $\gcd(x^2+1,x^3+1)=1$ so the Chinese remainder further says that the set of solutions is a single residue class modulo  $(x^2+1)(x^3+1)$. I suspect that you have covered a method for finding that residue class, so over to you at this point...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
First you need to find inverse of $x$ modulo $x^2+1$. Then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem idea.

For the inverses observe:

$$x^2+ 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{x^2+1,5} \implies x(4x) \equiv 1 \pmod{x^2+1,5}.$$

Thus the second congruence can be written as 
$$xf(x) \equiv x+1 \pmod{x^2+1} \implies \color{blue}{f(x) \equiv (4x)(x+1) \equiv 4x+1 \pmod{x^2+1,5}}.$$

Can you procced from here?